# java database not found

Tags: java, database, derby

He tells me not find the database, but the database is located in that directory. How do I solve the problem?

```
String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
Class.forName(driver);
String url = "jdbc:derby:C/Users/Calogero/workspace/CDStore/DB_CD_STORE";
```

Comment: can you please provide some more details like code,configuration,stacktrac or something..

Comment: Could you be missing a `:` after the drive letter? See https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop14.html#HDRDEVELOP846402

Comment: you must have to provide the proper url of database in your code and it also have missing localhost.I use like that String url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/database_name"; and also add jar file to your project before running it

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your database is created or not?
for the URl could you please use as below

```
jdbc:derby:C/Users/Calogero/workspace/CDStore/DB_CD_STORE;create=true
```

for more help please have a [Look](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/connect-to-apache-derby-java-db-via-jdbc)